# GBase Snippets Feed, how do I extract the URL?

Tags: python, gdata-api, gdata

In this example http://code.google.com/apis/base/docs/1.0/pythondevguide.html (search for entry.title.text) it gives `entry.title.text` as the only example for a Snippets feed attribute. What do I put there to get the URL? I was able to find entry.link but it only gives me `[<atom.Link object at 0x020E6E90>, <atom.Link object at 0x020E6EF0>]`

What's the 3rd part of the puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL from the link's `href` attribute:

```
for link in entry.link:
    print link.href
```

Comment: You're a wizard, I tried EVERYTHING, ... how did you figure this out?

Comment: When you can't locate the code you need in the api docs, you can drop into the interpreter and do `help(link)` to see if a docstring exists, or introspect the object with `print dir(link)` to list its attributes.  Glad I could help, good luck!

Comment: Well not not only do I know how to get it to work, I also know how to work around shoddy docs, thank again :)